# Java Android - Background Clipboard Service

Tags: android, clipboard

Im trying to do a background clipboard listener service,
that when detects a url on clipboard show some options.
There its my service code:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
....
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        String data2check = ((String) clipboard.getText());
        try {
            checkPaste("data2check");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
....
```

But in all ways that I try I receives always the same error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method
```

I think that the problem its that I cant access to `getSystemService` from a service.
If anyone can help me, thanks.

Comment: Background access to clipboard was disabled in android 10 due to privacy reasons. Only system and currently selected input method (keyboard) can access it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove double quotes at checkPaste("data2check").
Try below code:

```
     public class MyService extends Service {
     ....
         public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
         ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    String data2check = ((String) clipboard.getText());
    try {
        checkPaste(data2check);//edited line
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```